# PHP PDO Query isn't reading bind values

Tags: php, pdo, execute

So I'm trying to execute the following sql query:

```
$stmt = $connect->query("SELECT `FID`,`StorageID`,`DestructionDate` FROM `files` WHERE `DestructionDate` < ':date'");
$stmt->bindValue(":date",$date);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$fid = $row['FID'];
echo  $fid . " ";
}
```

The above code will return all records from files, it simply ignores the WHERE statement at all, and just to be clear, when I run the same statement on phpMyAdmin it runs just fine, in fact I even tried binding the value inside the query itself like this

```
$stmt = $connect->query("SELECT FID,StorageID,DestructionDate FROM files WHERE DestructionDate < '$date'");
```

And the query was executed correctly and only gave me the records that satisfy the WHERE condition, so the error is definitely in the bindValue() and execute() lines.

Comment: Don't put your `:date` parameter between single quotes

Comment: The single quotes are for the statement itself, The original statement would be something like: SELECT `FID`,`StorageID`,`DestructionDate` FROM `files` WHERE `DestructionDate` < '2018-10-30 13:00' The code didn't run without them

Comment: For prepared statements you do not and should not have quotes surrounding the placeholders, `:date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php):

> `PDO::query` — **Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set** as a PDOStatement object

You possibly want `PDO::prepare()` followed by `PDOStatement::execute()`. (There's normally no need to painfully bind params one by one.)

Additionally, you have bogus quotes around the placeholder:

```
':date'
```

You'll note that as soon as you execute the statement because params won't match.

Comment: You're correct I fixed it, but the issue remains, it's still returning all the records, here's the edited code $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT `FID`,`StorageID`,`DestructionDate` FROM `files` WHERE `DestructionDate` < '?'");
$stmt->execute(array($date));

Comment: Try `?` instead of `'?'`. You want the param's value, not a literal quote.

Comment: Oh finally it worked, Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions :

First:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT `FID`,`StorageID`,`DestructionDate` FROM `files` WHERE `DestructionDate` < :date");
$stmt->execute(array('date' => $date);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Second:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT `FID`,`StorageID`,`DestructionDate` FROM `files` WHERE `DestructionDate` < ?");
$stmt->execute(array($date));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In both cases, you don't need to 'quote' the string to be replaced (:date or ?) because PDO parse the value in the right type corresponding to the column to match.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! :)